# Getting parameter_rejected error in quickbook online integration

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have done this code:

```
static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Authenticating..");
        string consumerkey = "L0ORES0pf0uEody1YDI3sTkTpyBGaDVVnVRBb1krprkrghPWLQ";
        string consumerSecret = "NAONcYrwGgpkFCJN2BgXZHjG8YLqn1JWMEPDXIMg";
        string REQUEST_TOKEN_URL = "https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_request_token";
        string ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = "https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_access_token";

        string OauthLink = "https://developer.intuit.com/v2/OAuth2Playground/RedirectUrl";
        var consumerContext = new OAuthConsumerContext
        {
            ConsumerKey = consumerkey,
            ConsumerSecret = consumerSecret,
            SignatureMethod = SignatureMethod.HmacSha1
        };
        IOAuthSession AuthSession = new OAuthSession(consumerContext,REQUEST_TOKEN_URL, OauthLink, ACCESS_TOKEN_URL);
        IToken requestToken = AuthSession.GetRequestToken();

    }
```

And I am getting error : An unhandled exception of type 'DevDefined.OAuth.Framework.OAuthException' occurred in DevDefined.OAuth.dll Additional information: parameter_rejected

I have attached screenshot of my error.

[image]

What is quickbook online Request token URL and Access token URL for OAuth 2.0?

Comment: It's hard to read the error message from the image. Please paste the error to your question in string format.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'DevDefined.OAuth.Framework.OAuthException' occurred in DevDefined.OAuth.dll



Additional information: parameter_rejected

Comment: I am having the same issue. It's hard to catch this, however, because the code I am attempting to use (from https://github.com/IntuitDeveloper/C2QB-library-for-Windows-CUI-and-GUI ) is threading a task which is doing the handshake and failing. If you inspect the details of the exception, you will see a 'Report' field (of type -  Report {oauth_problem=parameter_rejected&oauth_parameters_rejected=oauth_consumer_key} DevDefined.OAuth.Framework.OAuthProblemReport
)  containing which parameter (in my case, {oauth_problem=parameter_rejected&oauth_parameters_rejected=oauth_consumer_key} .

Comment: @User_2235 Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Oauth2.0 //Refresh and Get New Access Token through WebClient and build ServiceContext for CRUD operations

Access Token will expire in every 60 minutes

```
        string URI = "https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer";
        string myParameters = "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=L0115-----------------------------------"; // Put Refresh Token

        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "application/json";
        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic UT------------------------------hcW5SV---------------------Qg==";  // Add Auth Token
        string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI, myParameters);
        wc.Dispose();

        var jobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(HtmlResult);


        string accessToken = jobject.access_token;


        string relmid = "123412341234123421341234";  // Relmid 

        OAuth2RequestValidator oauthValidator = new OAuth2RequestValidator(accessToken);
        ServiceContext serviceContext = new ServiceContext(relmid, IntuitServicesType.QBO, oauthValidator);
        serviceContext.IppConfiguration.BaseUrl.Qbo = "https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/";
        //serviceContext.IppConfiguration.BaseUrl.Qbo = "https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/";//prod
        serviceContext.IppConfiguration.MinorVersion.Qbo = "23";

        CustomerCRUD.CustomerAddTestUsingoAuth(serviceContext);

        CustomerCRUD.CustomerFindAllTestUsingoAuth(serviceContext);
```